# Why wasn't the need for dark matter recognized until the 80's?

Tags: astrophysics

The need for [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Early_history) was recognized in the 1980's, after Rubin and Ford presented their results on the rotation curves of galaxies. However, as early as the 30's, Fritz Zwicky inferred that there was some dark mass from the movements of galaxies in the Coma cluster.

Why was dark matter ignored between 1940 and the 1970's? What kept it from being recognized before the 80's?

Comment: Because it takes abundant evidence to accept a new type of matter, not a bold hunch based on observing a single anomaly. Astronomical anomalies arise routinely and are often resolved by more conventional means. See e.g. [de Swart, Deciphering dark matter](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02603-7):"*while studying Hubble’s observations of the Coma Cluster of galaxies, he noted an anomaly. Zwicky posited that an as-yet unobserved type of mass, dunkle Materie (dark matter) might explain it... However, it took another three decades for the phenomenon to be observed widely*".

Comment: Was any simple explanation proposed at the time?

Comment: There was no perceived need for an "explanation" until the 1980's.  It must be appreciated how _miniscule_ the sets of measurements of such things as individual galactic motions were before about 30-40 years ago.  What began to put "dark matter" over as a serious proposition was the growing accumulation of measured galactic rotation curves in the 1970's and '80's, in which it was discovered that a rather large proportion of outer galactic disks rotated too rapidly to be explained by the density of visible stars and "Keplerian motion".